# Problem assigning integer value in dataframe with mixed dtypes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with four columns, with dtypes set up like this (hat tip to ryanjdillon!)

```
dtypes = np.dtype([
      ('size', int),
      ('sum', float),
      ('mean', float),
      ('std', float),
      ])
data = np.empty(0, dtype=dtypes)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

At this stage, df.dtypes looks like this:

```
size      int64
sum     float64
mean    float64
std     float64
dtype: object
```

Great so far. But the first time I assign an int value to the 'size' column, e.g.

```
df.loc['foo', 'size'] = 1
```

it flips the dtype of the column to float64, and the value is cast, to 1.0 in this case.

```
size    float64
sum     float64
mean    float64
std     float64
dtype: object
```

Wazzup here?

Comment: you don't assign an int value to the size. In your code: df['foo', 'size'] = 1 means you ADD another column. did you mean: df.loc['foo', 'size'] = 1 (where foo is the index and 1 goes to size)?

Comment: My bad. I did df.loc['foo', 'size'] = 1 and got a new row, with index 'foo', and the value of 'size' = 1.0

Comment: so your question is WHY is it like this (as in what's going on under the hood) or how to fix it?

Comment: A little of both, I guess. I found some ugly ways to get around it (say, by initializing the int column with zeros in the constructor). But maybe understanding what's going on under the hood would help me avoid the hackery.

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do is simply use "astype('int64')" in your example: df['size']=df['size'].astype('int64')